# Thread won't die and two of them keep overlapping

Tags: java, multithreading

I need a thread that will only run once at a time, for example if it's called for the first time it will run, if it is called a second time, the first should stop completely and be allowed to die and a new one should take it's place.
I was ran a small test to see what was actually happening between each execution, the results show that the thread doesnt die but instead two threads are being executed alongside:

```
public class Test {
    Worker worker = new Worker();

    @Override
    public void valid() {

        try {
            if (worker.running) {
                worker.running = false;
                worker.join();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            worker.running = false;
        }

        worker = new Worker();

        worker.start();

    }

    private final class Worker extends Thread {
        private volatile boolean running = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
//Upon first execution
Thread-4
Thread-4
Thread-4
Thread-4

//When I execute it again
Thread-7
Thread-4
Thread-7
Thread-4
Thread-7
Thread-4
```

I've tried using `ExecutorService` or using `while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted)` instead of the boolean flag, and got the same results.
How can I properly stop "Thread-4" and have only one of them running?

The actual issue comes from a thread that will cycle through a list and update things on discord chat by request, what the thread does is listen to input and change as suggested by kidney I'm trying to use executor.submit() and Future

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private Future<Void> worker;

    private void setupImageThread() {

        if (!worker.isDone() && !worker.isCancelled()) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }

        this.worker = (Future<Void>)executor.submit(new Cycler(Listener.queue(), this.links, Cel.cMember()));

        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable timeout = () -> {

            executor.shutdown();

        };

        ses.schedule(timeout, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

How can I go about initializing the Future for the first time it is created?

Comment: How are Test objects created? How is Test.valid called?

Comment: It's called by User input from an EventListener, when it's called it just runs valid() once, the class actually implents a Functional Interface with the method. This is from a Discord JDA project if it matters.

Comment: We're guaranteed that we create one Test instance?  And then call valid() multiple times on that same instance?  (I have no theory here of the problem, I'm just trying to grasp the overall picture)

Comment: The way it's created is that a reference to the class is stored in an Enum constant as TEST(Test::new), every time it's called it invokes the valid method from the specified class using a `Supplier` so I guess it's a new instance every time? I'm fairly new to multithreading so I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: I would suggest using a [single thread executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--), which guarantees sequential task processing.

Comment: I tried this right now using 
`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`
Seems like a new pool is created when I run it the second time  
`pool-2-thread-1
pool-3-thread-1
pool-2-thread-1
pool-3-thread-1`

Comment: Why would you call it twice? Only one executor should be used. Maybe show some more code to get a better understanding of the context.

Comment: The actual context where it'll be used is a cycler for a list of images, so when the user types "next" for example it will cycle to the next image (This all happens in the Discord chat). The problem lies when the image command is called a second time, the cycler is acting on the old list which should be deactivated and replaced by the new one, I'll add more information to the question.

Comment: If you're creating multiple Test instances then expect one worker to be executing per instance.  There is no way in your code for the second instance to affect the worker from the first instance.

Comment: Incidentally, that's not a "multithreading" issue.  It's the difference between a "class" and an "instance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [single thread executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--), I would try something like this:

```java
public class Test {

    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Future<Void> worker;

    public Test() {
        this.worker = executor.submit(new Worker());
    }

    @Override
    public void valid() {
        if (!worker.isDone() && !worker.isCancelled()) {
            worker.cancel(true);  // Depends on whether you want to interrupt or not
        }

        this.worker = executor.submit(new Worker());
    }
}
```

And make `Worker` implement `Runnable`.

Comment: Won't `Future<Worker> worker` be null at the point of checking if it's done on the first execution? It's throwing a NullPointerException on that line.

Comment: Yes of course, I left the initialization up to you, I don't know the exact conditions. You can submit the first worker in a constructor, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how would I go about initializing it.
 And also I get a Type mismatch error from Future<?> to Future<Worker> is it correct to just add a cast to (Future<Worker>)?

Comment: Sorry, the type was incorrect, for `Runnable`, the type of `Future` should be `Void`. You may need to cast it, but the cast should be ok. I updated the answer...

Comment: I updated the question with more information on the actual class that is called, it is run the same way as the Test one, There's a method before it that fills a list with Image URL and then that method is called to setup the thread, the Cycler class actually has parameters so starting it in the constructor wouldn't work correctly

Comment: If there is no special logic needed on initialization, you can really call it in the constructor (as I did in the edited answer). Or you can have an `init` method, which would be called from code which is responsible for application life cycle...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the method `valid` can be called several times simultaneously. That means, every of those calls will wait to end only for one thread (Worker), whereas, every of them creates its own `Worker` and you lose a pointer to it, so it impossible to stop bunch of new created workers.
You should make the `valid` method synchronized: `synchronized void valid()` it will prevent creating many workers:

```
@Override
synchronized public void valid() {
    ...
}
```

One more thing to say. You put the while loop outside the try-catch, which is wrong: if the tread gets interrupted, the interruption doesn't kill it, because next interation gets started, so it should be like that:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    catch (InterruptedException iex) {
       //you don't need here Thread.currentThread().interrupt() call, because the thread has alredy been interrupted. 
       // The return statement here is also obsolete, I just use it as an example, but you can use empty braces.
       return; 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, if you make `valid` synchronized, it will just prevent its concurrent invocations. But since it spins a new thread for each invocation, new workers can be created this way...

Comment: Yes, but there always will be only one worker thread. Author's problem is that his code creates bunch of threads and he looses pointers to them, so it's impossible to spot them and we have the situation the topic started has described.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Suppose the class is created, so a worker thread is started and running. A second later, `valid` is called. A new worker thread will be created, the original marked for stopping, but it will keep running for another second. Which my understanding of the question. But of course, if `valid` is called concurrently, it will created unstoppable worker threads.

Comment: No, a new thread Worker won't be created till current Worker stopped, because there's `worker.join()` called.